# Error encountered while parsing GraalVM Nashorn FavaFXPorts Android

Tags: maven, graalvm, javafxports, gluonfx

So I'm currently trying to port a preexisting JavaFX project to Android using GluonFX/JavaFXPorts, and I've gotten stuck on this strange error during  the build:

```
Process
=======
compile

Command Line
============
/home/g3xu4l/graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0/bin/native-image -Djdk.internal.lambda.eagerlyInitialize=false --no-server -H:+SharedLibrary -H:+AddAllCharsets -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces -H:-DeadlockWatchdogExitOnTimeout -H:DeadlockWatchdogInterval=0 -H:+RemoveSaturatedTypeFlows -H:+ExitAfterRelocatableImageWrite --features=org.graalvm.home.HomeFinderFeature -H:TempDirectory=/mnt/c/Users/g3xu4/Downloads/try try again/test-project/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/tmp -H:EnableURLProtocols=http,https -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=/mnt/c/Users/g3xu4/Downloads/try try again/test-project/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/reflectionconfig-aarch64-android.json -H:JNIConfigurationFiles=/mnt/c/Users/g3xu4/Downloads/try try again/test-project/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/jniconfig-aarch64-android.json -H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=/mnt/c/Users/g3xu4/Downloads/try try again/test-project/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/resourceconfig-aarch64-android.json -H:-SpawnIsolates -Dsvm.targetArch=aarch64 -H:+ForceNoROSectionRelocations --libc=bionic -H:+UseCAPCache -H:CAPCacheDir=/mnt/c/Users/g3xu4/Downloads/try try again/test-project/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/capcache -H:CompilerBackend=lir -H:IncludeResourceBundles=com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/resources/controls,com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/resources/controls-nt,com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumMessagesBundle,com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaErrors,com.sun.webkit.graphics.Images,com.sun.webkit.LocalizedStrings,javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditorSkin,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.msg.XMLMessages -Dsvm.platform=org.graalvm.nativeimage.Platform$LINUX_AARCH64 -cp /root/.m2/repository/com/gluonhq/substrate/0.0.58/substrate-0.0.58.jar:/mnt/c/Users/g3xu4/Downloads/try try again/test-project/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/tmp/classpathJar.jar com.test-project.main.Main

Output
======
Warning: Ignoring server-mode native-image argument --no-server.
========================================================================================================================
GraalVM Native Image: Generating 'com.test-project.main.main' (shared library)...
========================================================================================================================
[1/7] Initializing...                                                                                   (56.6s @ 0.16GB)
 Version info: 'GraalVM 22.1.0 Java 17 CE'
 Garbage collector: Serial GC
[2/7] Performing analysis...  []                                                                        (29.5s @ 2.52GB)
  10,671 (93.56%) of 11,406 classes reachable
  15,765 (65.67%) of 24,008 fields reachable
  30,086 (82.19%) of 36,604 methods reachable
     316 classes,     0 fields, and     0 methods registered for reflection

2 fatal errors detected:
Fatal error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError$ParsingError: Error encountered while parsing org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.LinkerCallSite$TracingLinkerCallSite.setTarget(java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle) 
Parsing context:
   at org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.LinkerCallSite$TracingLinkerCallSite.setTarget(LinkerCallSite.java:327)
   at jdk.dynalink.support.AbstractRelinkableCallSite.initialize(AbstractRelinkableCallSite.java:101)
   at jdk.dynalink.DynamicLinker.link(DynamicLinker.java:192)
   at org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.Bootstrap.bootstrap(Bootstrap.java:223)
   at org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.Bootstrap.createDynamicInvoker(Bootstrap.java:351)
   at org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.Bootstrap.createDynamicCallInvoker(Bootstrap.java:362)

    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError.parsingError(AnalysisError.java:152)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.createTypeFlow(MethodTypeFlow.java:319)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.ensureTypeFlowCreated(MethodTypeFlow.java:290)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.addContext(MethodTypeFlow.java:111)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.DefaultAnalysisPolicy$DefaultVirtualInvokeTypeFlow.onObservedUpdate(DefaultAnalysisPolicy.java:252)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.TypeFlow.update(TypeFlow.java:552)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.PointsToAnalysis$1.run(PointsToAnalysis.java:631)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.executeCommand(CompletionExecutor.java:193)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.lambda$executeService$0(CompletionExecutor.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
Caused by: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError: parsing had failed in another thread
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError.shouldNotReachHere(AnalysisError.java:176)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisMethod.ensureGraphParsed(AnalysisMethod.java:621)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.phases.InlineBeforeAnalysisGraphDecoder.lookupEncodedGraph(InlineBeforeAnalysis.java:180)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.doInline(PEGraphDecoder.java:1145)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.tryInline(PEGraphDecoder.java:1128)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.trySimplifyInvoke(PEGraphDecoder.java:982)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.handleInvoke(PEGraphDecoder.java:936)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.nodes.GraphDecoder.processNextNode(GraphDecoder.java:788)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.phases.InlineBeforeAnalysisGraphDecoder.processNextNode(InlineBeforeAnalysis.java:240)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.nodes.GraphDecoder.decode(GraphDecoder.java:529)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.decode(PEGraphDecoder.java:812)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.phases.InlineBeforeAnalysis.decodeGraph(InlineBeforeAnalysis.java:98)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.parse(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:174)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.apply(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:357)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.createTypeFlow(MethodTypeFlow.java:301)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser$BytecodeParserError: com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.DeletedElementException: Unsupported method java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.setCallSiteTargetNormal(CallSite, MethodHandle) is reachable
To diagnose the issue, you can add the option --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime. The unsupported element is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
    at parsing java.lang.invoke.CallSite.setTargetNormal(CallSite.java:290)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.throwParserError(BytecodeParser.java:2505)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.throwParserError(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:105)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3366)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.handleBytecodeBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3318)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3163)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.build(BytecodeParser.java:1138)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.buildRootMethod(BytecodeParser.java:1030)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.GraphBuilderPhase$Instance.run(GraphBuilderPhase.java:84)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase.run(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:79)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.run(Phase.java:49)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.BasePhase.apply(BasePhase.java:236)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:42)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:38)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.AnalysisParsedGraph.parseBytecode(AnalysisParsedGraph.java:135)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisMethod.ensureGraphParsed(AnalysisMethod.java:586)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.phases.InlineBeforeAnalysisGraphDecoder.lookupEncodedGraph(InlineBeforeAnalysis.java:180)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.doInline(PEGraphDecoder.java:1145)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.tryInline(PEGraphDecoder.java:1128)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.trySimplifyInvoke(PEGraphDecoder.java:982)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.handleInvoke(PEGraphDecoder.java:936)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.nodes.GraphDecoder.processNextNode(GraphDecoder.java:788)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.phases.InlineBeforeAnalysisGraphDecoder.processNextNode(InlineBeforeAnalysis.java:240)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.nodes.GraphDecoder.decode(GraphDecoder.java:529)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.decode(PEGraphDecoder.java:812)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.phases.InlineBeforeAnalysis.decodeGraph(InlineBeforeAnalysis.java:98)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.parse(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:174)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.apply(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:357)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.createTypeFlow(MethodTypeFlow.java:301)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.ensureTypeFlowCreated(MethodTypeFlow.java:290)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.addContext(MethodTypeFlow.java:111)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.DefaultAnalysisPolicy$DefaultVirtualInvokeTypeFlow.onObservedUpdate(DefaultAnalysisPolicy.java:252)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.TypeFlow.update(TypeFlow.java:552)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.PointsToAnalysis$1.run(PointsToAnalysis.java:631)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.executeCommand(CompletionExecutor.java:193)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.lambda$executeService$0(CompletionExecutor.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.externalHelpQuiescePool(ForkJoinPool.java:2104)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.awaitQuiescence(ForkJoinPool.java:3321)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.complete(CompletionExecutor.java:243)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.PointsToAnalysis.doTypeflow(PointsToAnalysis.java:688)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.PointsToAnalysis.finish(PointsToAnalysis.java:676)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.PointsToAnalysis.runAnalysis(PointsToAnalysis.java:732)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:723)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:558)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:515)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:407)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:585)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:128)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner$JDK9Plus.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:615)
Caused by: com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.DeletedElementException: Unsupported method java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.setCallSiteTargetNormal(CallSite, MethodHandle) is reachable
To diagnose the issue, you can add the option --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime. The unsupported element is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.lookup(AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.java:200)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.infrastructure.SubstitutionProcessor$ChainedSubstitutionProcessor.lookup(SubstitutionProcessor.java:140)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.infrastructure.SubstitutionProcessor$ChainedSubstitutionProcessor.lookup(SubstitutionProcessor.java:140)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.lookupAllowUnresolved(AnalysisUniverse.java:425)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.infrastructure.WrappedConstantPool.lookupMethod(WrappedConstantPool.java:125)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.lookupMethodInPool(BytecodeParser.java:4173)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.lookupMethodInPool(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:133)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.lookupMethod(BytecodeParser.java:4167)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genInvokeStatic(BytecodeParser.java:1636)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBytecode(BytecodeParser.java:5218)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3358)
    ... 47 more
Fatal error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError$ParsingError: Error encountered while parsing org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.LinkerCallSite$ProfilingLinkerCallSite.setTarget(java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle) 
Parsing context:
   at org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.LinkerCallSite$ProfilingLinkerCallSite.setTarget(LinkerCallSite.java:207)
   at jdk.dynalink.support.AbstractRelinkableCallSite.initialize(AbstractRelinkableCallSite.java:101)
   at jdk.dynalink.DynamicLinker.link(DynamicLinker.java:192)
   at org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.Bootstrap.bootstrap(Bootstrap.java:223)
   at org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.Bootstrap.createDynamicInvoker(Bootstrap.java:351)
   at org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.Bootstrap.createDynamicCallInvoker(Bootstrap.java:362)

    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError.parsingError(AnalysisError.java:152)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.createTypeFlow(MethodTypeFlow.java:319)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.ensureTypeFlowCreated(MethodTypeFlow.java:290)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.addContext(MethodTypeFlow.java:111)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.DefaultAnalysisPolicy$DefaultVirtualInvokeTypeFlow.onObservedUpdate(DefaultAnalysisPolicy.java:252)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.TypeFlow.update(TypeFlow.java:552)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.PointsToAnalysis$1.run(PointsToAnalysis.java:631)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.executeCommand(CompletionExecutor.java:193)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.lambda$executeService$0(CompletionExecutor.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.externalHelpQuiescePool(ForkJoinPool.java:2104)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.awaitQuiescence(ForkJoinPool.java:3321)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.complete(CompletionExecutor.java:243)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.PointsToAnalysis.doTypeflow(PointsToAnalysis.java:688)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.PointsToAnalysis.finish(PointsToAnalysis.java:676)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.PointsToAnalysis.runAnalysis(PointsToAnalysis.java:732)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:723)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:558)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:515)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:407)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:585)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:128)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner$JDK9Plus.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:615)
Caused by: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError: parsing had failed in another thread
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError.shouldNotReachHere(AnalysisError.java:176)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisMethod.ensureGraphParsed(AnalysisMethod.java:621)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.phases.InlineBeforeAnalysisGraphDecoder.lookupEncodedGraph(InlineBeforeAnalysis.java:180)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.doInline(PEGraphDecoder.java:1145)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.tryInline(PEGraphDecoder.java:1128)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.trySimplifyInvoke(PEGraphDecoder.java:982)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.handleInvoke(PEGraphDecoder.java:936)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.nodes.GraphDecoder.processNextNode(GraphDecoder.java:788)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.phases.InlineBeforeAnalysisGraphDecoder.processNextNode(InlineBeforeAnalysis.java:240)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.nodes.GraphDecoder.decode(GraphDecoder.java:529)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.decode(PEGraphDecoder.java:812)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.phases.InlineBeforeAnalysis.decodeGraph(InlineBeforeAnalysis.java:98)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.parse(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:174)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.apply(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:357)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.createTypeFlow(MethodTypeFlow.java:301)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser$BytecodeParserError: com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.DeletedElementException: Unsupported method java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.setCallSiteTargetNormal(CallSite, MethodHandle) is reachable
To diagnose the issue, you can add the option --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime. The unsupported element is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
    at parsing java.lang.invoke.CallSite.setTargetNormal(CallSite.java:290)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.throwParserError(BytecodeParser.java:2505)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.throwParserError(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:105)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3366)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.handleBytecodeBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3318)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3163)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.build(BytecodeParser.java:1138)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.buildRootMethod(BytecodeParser.java:1030)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.GraphBuilderPhase$Instance.run(GraphBuilderPhase.java:84)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase.run(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:79)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.run(Phase.java:49)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.BasePhase.apply(BasePhase.java:236)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:42)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:38)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.AnalysisParsedGraph.parseBytecode(AnalysisParsedGraph.java:135)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisMethod.ensureGraphParsed(AnalysisMethod.java:586)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.DeletedElementException: Unsupported method java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.setCallSiteTargetNormal(CallSite, MethodHandle) is reachable
To diagnose the issue, you can add the option --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime. The unsupported element is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.lookup(AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.java:200)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.infrastructure.SubstitutionProcessor$ChainedSubstitutionProcessor.lookup(SubstitutionProcessor.java:140)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.infrastructure.SubstitutionProcessor$ChainedSubstitutionProcessor.lookup(SubstitutionProcessor.java:140)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.lookupAllowUnresolved(AnalysisUniverse.java:425)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.infrastructure.WrappedConstantPool.lookupMethod(WrappedConstantPool.java:125)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.lookupMethodInPool(BytecodeParser.java:4173)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.lookupMethodInPool(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:133)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.lookupMethod(BytecodeParser.java:4167)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genInvokeStatic(BytecodeParser.java:1636)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBytecode(BytecodeParser.java:5218)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3358)
    ... 47 more
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                       12.4s (14.1% of total time) in 23 GCs | Peak RSS: 6.99GB | CPU load: 6.48
========================================================================================================================
Failed generating 'com.test-project.main.main' after 1m 26s.
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1


Result
======
result:
```

It seems to be similar to [this](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/2736) which was patched out in a version that I can't use because it's not compatible with the plugin. Normally, I'd chalk this down to an outdated program and give up, but I've tried the most similar sample project I could find and building works fine, so it's either an incompatibility with the specific program I've chosen to port (probably the JavaFX controller) or an issue with the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>g3xu4l</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-project</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.4.8.7</version>
    <name>Test Project</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>18.0.2</javafx.version>
        <nashorn.version>15.4</nashorn.version>
        <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
        <maven-shade-plugin.version>3.3.0</maven-shade-plugin.version>
        <maven-compile-plugin.version>3.10.1</maven-compile-plugin.version>
        <gluonfx.maven.plugin.version>1.0.18</gluonfx.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>windows</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>Windows</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <target.platform>win</target.platform>
                <exclude.platform>linux</exclude.platform>
                <gluonfx.target>host</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>linux</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>Linux</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <target.platform>linux</target.platform>
                <exclude.platform>win</exclude.platform>
                <gluonfx.target>host</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <target.platform>win</target.platform>
                <gluonfx.target>ios</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <target.platform>win</target.platform>
                <gluonfx.target>android</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <classifier>${target.platform}</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <classifier>${target.platform}</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <classifier>${target.platform}</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <classifier>${target.platform}</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <classifier>${target.platform}</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <classifier>${target.platform}</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjdk.nashorn</groupId>
            <artifactId>nashorn-core</artifactId>
            <version>${nashorn.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/com/test-project/res</directory>
                <targetPath>com/test-project/res</targetPath>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>res</directory>
                <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/${project.name} (${target.platform})/res</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gluonfx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>${gluonfx.target}</target>
                    <mainClass>com.test-project.main.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compile-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.test-project.main.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-shade-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>project-classifier</shadedClassifierName>
                            <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.name} (${target.platform})/${project.name}-${project.version}.jar</outputFile>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.test-project.Launcher</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

A few notes:

- Currently running on WSL2 Debian but using a file stored in the main Windows storage area.
- The sample file works perfectly and is currently installed on my phone despite also being stored outside WSL.
- The program runs fine with `mvn gluonfx:run`.

So far I've tried several different methods of integrating the plugin into the preexisting pom.xml to no avail. The program takes around an hour to build, so I can't experiment too much. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: It is probably something with the actual code of the project not working with FavaFXPorts; I copied the pom.xml into the sample project and it ran just fine.

Comment: See in the error message: "you can add the option --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime". Add that option with `<nativeImageArgs/>` and try again?